# Does a face-down creature with morph retain its damage when it is turned face up?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-face-down-cards

I have a face-down morph creature that has received 1 point of damage. If my opponent casts [Shock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShock%5d) or another thing to kill it, can I flip at that point to make the damage disappear or my card still have it (now flipped) until the end of my turn?

Answer (score 10):

After turning the creature face up, the damage is still marked on the creature, it doesn't somehow disappear. It's still the same creature, only in a different 'state'.

> 120.6. Damage marked on a creature remains until the cleanup step
>
> 707.8. As a face-down permanent is turned face up, its copiable values revert to its normal copiable values. Any effects that have been applied to the face-down permanent still apply to the face-up permanent.

But if the creature has a high enough toughness (4 or more) or protection from red, it might still survive the Shock.

Note that turning a creature face up doesn't use the stack, so an opponent cannot cast a Shock in response to turning a creature face up to kill it while it's still morphed.

Answer (score 4):

A creature that unmorphs has not left play.   It is still the same game object as before, and any effects or damage applied to it will still apply.